# Auto increment ID with string

Tags: c#, winforms, auto-increment

I'm using Access 2000-2003 database for C#. I like to have my `TypeID` to have a unique id as `CHHTP001`, `CHHTP002` and etc, and display the id in `TextBox` before inserting new value in the database.

```
public void generateRateID()
{
     string id;
     con.Open();
     string rate = "SELECT MAX(TypeID) FROM tblRoomTypeRate";
     cmd = new OleDbCommand(rate, con);
     OleDbDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
     if (dr.Read())
     {
          id = dr[0].ToString();
          id = id + 1;
          txtRateID.Text = "CHHRT" + id.PadLeft(3, '0');
     }
     con.Close();
}
```

The display in `TextBox` is `CHHTP001` at first, then `CHHTPCHHTP0011`. How can I make the `CHHTPCHHTP0011` to `CHHTP002` and so on?

Comment: What is the actual value in the database at dr[0]?

Comment: No matter what format you're retrieving from the database for dr[0] you're converting it to a string and then attempting to add `1` to it - if your field is a numeric, you probably want to be leaving it as an int or whatever type it already is.  Then use string.Format() to set the textbox value.

Comment: dr[0] is column TypeID

Comment: but what type of field is TypeID?

Comment: Is the database going to be accessed by one or multiple users?

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Regex`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex(v=vs.110).aspx). This should works as you want:

```
id = dr[0].ToString();//CHHTP001 Or CHHTP111
id = Regex.Replace(id, "\\d+", m => (int.Parse(m.Value) + 1).ToString(new string('0', m.Value.Length)));
txtRateID.Text = id;//CHHTP002 Or CHHTP112
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is some general guidelines.

You should create an int variable that records what should be the number. That way you can manage your id easily. When you want to increment your id, just increment the variable.

When you want to convert the id to a string, first call `ToString` and `PadLeft`. Next you just concatenate the string to "CHHTP"! Isn't that easy?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

{

```
 string id;

 string literal; // "CHHRT" or whatever;

 int sequence;

 con.Open();
 string rate = "SELECT MAX(TypeID) FROM tblRoomTypeRate";
 cmd = new OleDbCommand(rate, con);
 OleDbDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
 if (dr.Read())
 {
     id = dr[0].ToString();
     sequence = int.Parse( new string( id.Where( char.IsDigit ).ToArray() ) );
     literal = new string( id.Where( char.IsLetter ).ToArray() );
     id = literal + ( sequence + 1 ).ToString( "000" );                
     txtRateID.Text = id;
 }
 con.Close();
```

}

Comment: Sorry, this is my first time. Since it is not possible to increase the id composed of a literal part and another numeric. I suggested to him use more two auxiliary variables, one containing the literal part and the other containing the numeric part of the id, thus facilitating concatenation of two different types of data. I used the Where () method to check each character and separate the literal part of the numeric portion of the id, and increase only the numerical part, giving more stability to the code that could be used for other literal-numeric combinations with no changes.